# Unable to upload data to local datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I am using the following command to upload to the local datastore, but It keeps prompting for authentication and It fails when i give my personal one. I havent created an App in the server yet, just created one locally and testing it. I am able to create a datastore and read and write data into it, I was trying to upload the actual data into it and wrote a loader script.but it isnt working as expected

`appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=loader.py --filename=Book1.csv --kind=Contact --url=http://localhost:8080/_ah/remote_api .`

my models.py is

```
from google.appengine.ext import db
class Contact(db.Model):
    phone_no = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    address = db.StringProperty()
    address_2 = db.StringProperty()
    city = db.StringProperty()
    state = db.StringProperty()
    zipcode = db.StringProperty()
    email_1 = db.StringProperty()
    email_2 = db.StringProperty()
```

and loader script is

```
import datetime
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.tools import bulkloader
import models

class ContactLoader(bulkloader.Loader):
    def __init__(self):
        bulkloader.Loader.__init__(self, 'Contact',
                                   [('phone_no', str),
                                    ('name', str),
                                    ('address',str),
                                    ('address_2', int),
                                    ('city', str),
                                    ('state',str),
                                    ('zipcode', str),
                                    ('email_1',str),
                                    ('email_2', str)
                                   ])

loaders = [ContactLoader]
`
```

Comment: You should be able to use any email/password to authenticate with the local server. What is the error message exactly?

Comment: `URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it>
[ERROR   ] Authentication Failed: Incorrect credentials or unsupported authentication type (e.g. OpenId).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's been lots of solutions to this question. But I've found that the easiest solution is to run the dev server from another command line window, (or PyCharm, if you have that), then run the command again from the other window.